# Grabbing the extension in a file name

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

How do I get the file extension from bash? Here's what I tried:

```
filename=`basename $filepath`
fileext=${filename##*.}
```

By doing that I can get extension of `bz2` from the path `/dir/subdir/file.bz2`, but I have a problem with the path `/dir/subdir/file-1.0.tar.bz2`.

I would prefer a solution using only bash without external programs if it is possible.

To make my question clear, I was creating a bash script to extract any given archive just by a single command of `extract path_to_file`. How to extract the file is determined by the script by seeing its compression or archiving type, that could be .tar.gz, .gz, .bz2 etc. I think this should involve string manipulation, for example if I get the extension `.gz` then I should check whether it has the string `.tar` before `.gz` — if so, the extension should be `.tar.gz`.

Comment: Related: [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/55075).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the file name is `file-1.0.tar.bz2`, the extension is `bz2`. The method you're using to extract the extension (`fileext=${filename##*.}`) is perfectly valid¹.

How do you decide that you want the extension to be `tar.bz2` and not `bz2` or `0.tar.bz2`? You need to answer this question first. Then you can figure out what shell command matches your specification.

- One possible specification is that extensions must begin with a letter. This heuristic fails for a few common extensions like `7z`, which might be best treated as a special case. Here's a bash/ksh/zsh implementation:

  ```
  basename=$filename; fileext=
  while [[ $basename = ?*.* &&
           ( ${basename##*.} = [A-Za-z]* || ${basename##*.} = 7z ) ]]
  do
    fileext=${basename##*.}.$fileext
    basename=${basename%.*}
  done
  fileext=${fileext%.}
  ```

  For POSIX portability, you need to use a `case` statement for pattern matching.

  ```
  while case $basename in
          ?*.*) case ${basename##*.} in [A-Za-z]*|7z) true;; *) false;; esac;;
          *) false;;
        esac
  do …
  ```
- Another possible specification is that some extensions denote encodings and indicate that further stripping is needed. Here's a bash/ksh/zsh implementation (requiring `shopt -s extglob` under bash and `setopt ksh_glob` under zsh):

  ```
  basename=$filename
  fileext=
  while [[ $basename = ?*.@(bz2|gz|lzma) ]]; do
    fileext=${basename##*.}.$fileext
    basename=${basename%.*}
  done
  if [[ $basename = ?*.* ]]; then
    fileext=${basename##*.}.$fileext
    basename=${basename%.*}
  fi
  fileext=${fileext%.}
  ```

  Note that this considers `0` to be an extension in `file-1.0.gz`.

¹ 
<sub>`${VARIABLE##SUFFIX}` and related constructs are in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), so they work in any non-antique Bourne-style shell such as ash, bash, ksh or zsh.</sub>

Comment: that should be solved, by checking if the string before last `.` token is archive type, for example `tar`, if its not archive type like `0` iteration should end.

Comment: @uray: that works in this particular case, but it's not a general solution. Consider [Maciej's example of `.patch.lzma`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/bash-get-file-extension/1573#1573). A better heuristic would be to consider the string *after* the last `.`: if it's a compression suffix (`.7z`, `.bz2`, `.gz`, ...), continue stripping.

Comment: @NoamM What was wrong with the indentation? It's definitely broken after your edit: doubly-nested code is indented the same as singly-nested.

Answer (score 39):

You might simplify matters by just doing pattern matching on the filename rather than extracting the extension twice:

```
case "$filename" in
    *.tar.bz2) bunzip_then_untar ;;
    *.bz2)     bunzip_only ;;
    *.tar.gz)  untar_with -z ;;
    *.tgz)     untar_with -z ;;
    *.gz)      gunzip_only ;;
    *.zip)     unzip ;;
    *.7z)      do something ;;
    *)         do nothing ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$ echo "thisfile.txt"|awk -F . '{print $NF}'
```

Comments on this here: http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2007/09/29/short-tip-get-file-extension-in-shell-script/

Comment: not work for `.tar.gz` extension

Comment: Well a .tar.gz is actually a tar inside a gzip file so it does work in the sense that it removes a gz extension from a gzip file.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my shot at it: Translate dots to newlines, pipe through `tail`, get last line:

```
$> TEXT=123.234.345.456.456.567.678
$> echo $TEXT | tr . \\n | tail -n1
678
```

Answer (score 1):

One day I've created those tricky functions:

```
# args: string how_many
function get_last_letters(){ echo ${1:${#1}-$2:$2}; }
function cut_last_letters(){ echo ${1:0:${#1}-$2}; }
```

I've found this straightforward approach, very useful in many cases, not only when it goes about extensions.

For checking extensions - **It's simple and reliable**

```
~$ get_last_letters file.bz2 4
.bz2
~$ get_last_letters file.0.tar.bz2 4
.bz2
```

For cutting-off extension:

```
~$ cut_last_letters file.0.tar.bz2 4
file.0.tar
```

For changing extension:

```
~$ echo $(cut_last_letters file.0.tar.bz2 4).gz
file.0.tar.gz
```

Or, if you like "handy functions:

```
~$ function cut_last_letters_and_add(){ echo ${1:0:${#1}-$2}"$3"; }
~$ cut_last_letters_and_add file.0.tar.bz2 4 .gz
file.0.tar.gz
```

P.S. If you liked those functions or found them usedfull, please refer to this post :) (and hopefully put a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Note: this doesn't *just* answer the OP's question. Rather, it also answers the generic question posed by just the title of this question:

> Grabbing the extension in a file name

##### To answer the OP:

```bash
echo "/dir/subdir/file-1.0.tar.bz2" \
    | sed 's/.*\///' | grep -oE "\.[^0-9]*\..*$"
```

Output:

```
.tar.bz2
```

The `sed` part obtains just the string after the last `/`, and the `grep` part obtains the extension beginning with a period (`\.`), any number of chars *not* containing a number (`[^0-9]*`), and then a period followed by any char to the end of the line (`\..*$`).

##### General answer: how to extract just the extensions from a multi-line string containing a bunch of filenames

**...including extracting more-complicated extensions, such as `.tar.gz` from `file.10.5.2.tar.gz` (basically just ignoring numeric 0-9 portions of extensions).**

I really like this solution, piping the filenames to `sed 's/.*\///' | grep -oE "(^[^.]*$|\.[^0-9]*\..*$)" | sort -u`. The `grep` regex portion of the answer is pretty complicated because it needs to remove the portion of the extensions which contain numbers 0-9.

Example:

```bash
filenames_str="\
/some/file.txt
/whatever/prog.c
/something/abc.tar.bz
/something/abc.123.456.789.tar.bz
/something/abc.c
/something/abc.h
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever.7.pdf
/noextension"


echo "$filenames_str" \
    | sed 's/.*\///' | grep -oE "(^[^.]*$|(\.[^0-9])*(\.[^0-9]*$))" | sort -u
```

Output:

```bash
.c
.h
noextension
.pdf
.tar.bz
.tar.gz
.tar.gz.whatever
.txt
```

Explanation, from my answer here (although the above is modified from my other answer, to answer the OP's question above as well): [All about finding, filtering, and sorting with `find`, based on file size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731663/114401):

> The `sed` part retains just the contents after the last `/`. The `grep` part then keeps only the extension, including the dot (`.`), if it has one, and the whole string otherwise. And finally, `sort -u` removes duplicates to leave only unique strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${filename#$(echo $filename | sed 's/\.[^[:digit:]].*$//g;')}
```

For example:

```
% echo $filename
2.6.35-zen2.patch.lzma
% echo ${filename#$(echo $filename | sed 's/\.[^[:digit:]].*$//g;')}
.patch.lzma
```

Comment: Does not work for all cases. Try with 'foo.7z'

Comment: You need quotes, and better use `printf` in case the file name contains a backslash or begins with `-`: `"${filename#$(printf %s "$filename" | sed 's/\.[^[:digit:]].*$//g;')}"`

Comment: @axel_c: right, and I've implemented the same specification as Maciej as an example. What heuristic do you suggest that's better than “begins with a letter”?

Comment: @Gilles: i just think there's not a solution unless you use a precomputed list of known extensions, because an extension can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

the jackman case-based answer is pretty good and portable, but if you just want the filename and extension in a variable i've found this solution:

```
INPUTFILE="$1"
INPUTFILEEXT=$( echo -n "$INPUTFILE" | rev | cut -d'.' -f1 | rev )
INPUTFILEEXT=$( echo -n $INPUTFILEEXT | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' ) # force lowercase extension
INPUTFILENAME="`echo -n \"$INPUTFILE\" | rev | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev`"

# fix for files with multiple extensions like "gbamidi-v1.0.tar.gz"
INPUTFILEEXT2=$( echo -n "$INPUTFILENAME" | rev | cut -d'.' -f1 | rev )
if [ "$INPUTFILEEXT2" = "tar" ]; then
    # concatenate the extension
    INPUTFILEEXT="$INPUTFILEEXT2.$INPUTFILEEXT"
    # update the filename
    INPUTFILENAME="`echo -n \"$INPUTFILENAME\" | rev | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev`"
fi
```

It only works with double extensions and the first one must be "tar".

But you can change the "tar" test line with a string length test and repeat the fix multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put .IO.extension();'  file

#OR (handles up to an 8-part file extension):

~$ raku -ne 'put .IO.extension( :parts(^9) );'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
/test1/a/sample1.xls
/test2/demo.sh
/some/file.txt
/whatever/prog.c
/something/abc.tar.bz
/something/abc.123.456.789.tar.bz
/something/abc.c
/something/abc.h
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever.7.pdf
/noextension
```

Sample Output:

```
xls
sh
txt
c
tar.bz
123.456.789.tar.bz
c
h
10.5.2.tar.gz
10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever
10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever.7.pdf
```

Briefly, the file is read linewise using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. The code is run over each line: First the path is interpreted as an `IO` object, for which an `extension` can be identified/extracted. Within the `extension` parameters, adding the `:parts` parameter (a.k.a. "adverb") allows multi-part file-extension identification, in this case `:parts(^9)` means `0..8` parts.

Note, because filepaths are understood by Raku with OS-specific settings, the codes above *should work* unmodified on Windows to extract the correct extensions from Windows paths (i.e. Raku understands backslash as a path-separator on Windows OS).

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Path
https://docs.raku.org/routine/basename
https://docs.raku.org/routine/extension
https://raku.org

Example Source (thanks to @Gabriel_Staples):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731665/227738

Answer (score -1):

i solved it using this:

```
filename=`basename $filepath`
fileext=${filename##*.}
fileext2=${filename%.*}
fileext3=${fileext2##*.}
if [ "$fileext3" == "tar" ]; then
    fileext="tar."$fileext
fi
```

but this only work for known archiving type, in this case only `tar`