# How to change configuration of detox (dash instead underscore)?

Tags: command-line, scripting, filenames, rename

I found, best to this moment, a solution when changing all those annoying filenames in large quantities, making them readable and easier to manipulate with in command-line.

So I found, among many commands, a little piece of software called [detox](http://detox.sourceforge.net/). By default, it replaces spaces with `_`. Reading through manpages didn't gave me an anwser how to make detox rename files replacing spaces with `-`, instead.

```
[/] cd test
one five/  one four/  one one/  one three/  one two/
[test] detox *
[test] l
one_five/  one_four/  one_one/  one_three/  one_two/
[test]
```

How to do that?

I can't find `.detoxrc` file (or any of files related to this program) and if I create it, I don't know what to put in it.

P.S. Is there an alternative to detox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem that detox has an option for that. It should be fairly simple to modify the source code to add a filter with your desired output (a small modification of the `safe` filter; don't forget to ensure that any leading `-` gets removed).

You could postprocess the result of `detox`, or use other tools altogether. There are many file renaming tools that are more flexible.

The [Perl rename](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/bin/rename.PL) command (not to be confused with the util-linux `rename` command) supports transforming file names with arbitrary Perl code. This command is available as `rename` on Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …). It's available on Arch as [perl-rename](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/perl-rename/). If you just want to change `_` into `-` and strip leading `-`, you can use:

```
rename 's/_/-/g; s/\A-*//' *
```

This only affects files (except dot files) in the current directory. To act on a directory recursively, combine this with the `find` command.

```
find . -depth -exec rename 's/_/-/g; s/\A-*//' {} +
```

Other features of detox can be expressed in Perl, most of them with the [`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer). For example, to retain only letters and digits and replace any sequence of other characters with `-`, you can use

```
rename 's/[^[:alnum:]]+/-/g; s/\A-//' …
```

If you want to [approximate Unicode characters with ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309215/how-can-i-substitute-unicode-characters-with-ascii-in-perl), you can use [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Unidecode/):

```
perl -C -MText::Unidecode /usr/bin/rename '$_ = unidecode($_)' …
```

Another powerful renaming tool is the [zmv](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) command from the [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) shell. First run this (put it in your `~/.zshrc` for interactive use):

```
autoload -U zmv
```

To change `_` into `-` and strip leading `-`, you can use:

```
zmv '**/*' '$f:h/${${f##*/-#}//_/-}'
```

The pattern `**/*` makes this command act in subdirectories of the current directory recursively.

Comment: Currently, option `rename 's/_/-/g; s/\A-*//' *` works best for me. But, can you explain in short how to skip detox and replace not underscores, but spaces with dashes with this command? I don't understand it's structure, so I don't know how to change it.

Comment: @IgorVuckovic `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` replaces PATTERN (a Perl regular expression) by REPLACEMENT. The `g` suffix means to replace all occurrences (without it, only the first is replaced). For example `s/_/-/g` replaces each `_` by a `-`. `s/[^[:alnum:]]/-/` replaces each non-alphanumeric character by a `-`. `s/[^[:alnum:]]+/-/` replaces each sequence of non-alphanumeric characters by a single `-`. `s/ +/-/` replaces each sequence of spaces by a `-`. A `\A` at the beginning of the pattern means that the replacement is carried out at the beginning of the name only.

Answer (score 5):

At least as of detox version 1.2.0, the filtering can be customized (the following commands/locations may need to be changed depending on your distro). Firstly:

`cp /usr/share/detox/safe.tbl ~/mysafe.tbl`

Next edit the file `mysafe.tbl` searching for the word "space" (around line 127) and change the underscore to a hyphen.

Now modify `~/.detoxrc` e.g. as follows:

```
sequence hyphenated {
   safe {filename "/home/MY_USSERNAME/mysafe.tbl";};
   #wipeup {remove_trailing;};
};
```

(Replace "MY_USERNAME" of course...)

Now run the following command:

```
detox -vs hyphenated *
```

and you should be good to go :)

**Edit 20170801:** Detox seems to have some UTF-8 problems. Have created a few patches, emailed upstream and debian maints, now have to open a bug on some site called "github" or something - time to figure it out...