# How to list all files ordered by size

Tags: linux, files, ls

I would like to list all files in the order of big to small in size and the files could be present anywhere in a certain folder.

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/sorting-files-according-to-size-recursively

Comment: Do you mean “the files are in this directory”, or “the files may be in any sub-directory”.

Comment: If you are able / want to use a GUI tool, take a look at [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat), formerly [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 443):

Simply use something like:

```
ls -lS /path/to/folder/
```

Capital **S**.

This will sort files by size.

Also see:

[`man ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)

```
-S     sort by file size
```

If you want to sort in **reverse** order, just add `-r` switch.

**Update:**

To exclude directories (and provided none of the file names or symlink targets contain newline characters):

```
ls -lS | grep -v '^d'
```

**Update 2:**

I see now how it still shows symbolic links, which could be folders. Symbolic links always start with a letter l, as in link.

Change the command to filter for a `-`. This should only leave regular files:

```
ls -lS | grep '^-'
```

On my system this only shows regular files.

**update 3:**

To add recursion, I would leave the sorting of the lines to the `sort` command and tell it to use the 5th column to sort on.

```
ls -lR | grep '^-' | sort -k 5 -rn
```

`-rn` means Reverse and numeric to get the biggest files at the top. Down side of this command is that it does not show the full path of the files.

If you do need the full path of the files, use something like this:

```
find . -type f  -exec du -h {} + | sort -r -h
```

The `find` command will recursively find all files in all sub directories of `.` and call `du -h` (meaning *disk usage -humanreadable*) and then sort the output again. If your `find`/`sort` doesn't support `-h`, replace with `du -k` and `sort -rn`. Note that *size* and *disk usage* are not the same thing.

Comment: `du` gives the disk usage which is different from the file size. With (GNU) `du -h`, numerical sort won't work (you'll need the `-h` GNU option to sort). xargs expect a list of possibly quoted words as input so it won't work if filenames contain blanks or quoted characters.

Comment: I see that -S does descending size order, what about ascending order?

Comment: Following @StéphaneChazelas, this works for me: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh`. If you just want say the largest 30 files: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh | head -n 30`.

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain the `+ |` syntax in `+ | sort -r -h`?

Comment: @Victor, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command.

Comment: For Update 3 scenario, human readable would be `ls -lRh | grep '^-' | sort -k 5 -rh | less`

Comment: For those "lucky" enough to work in IBM z/OS USS, Update 3 gives the best resolution, as that version of `ls` does not have `-S`. I modified it slightly to create a function: `function lsS () { ls -l $* | grep '^-' | sort -k 5 -rn }`, which allows other `ls` flags to be used. It's not bulletproof, I just did this in a couple of minutes; if I ever need to harden it, I'll be back. (I would rather have `ls` do the file expansion, but `$*` makes it easy to support flags and not worry about if they're present on the command line.)

Answer (score 34):

You could use something like find and sort.

```
find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7
```

(the `-ls` option is not standard but is found in many find implementations, not only the GNU one. In GNU find and others, it displays something similar to `ls -li` with a few exceptions, for instance, files with ACLs are not marked with a +)

If the file names may contain newline characters, with GNU find and GNU sort:

```
find . -type f -ls -printf '\0' | sort -zk7rn | tr -d '\0'
```

Comment: This assumes "group" column (from -ls) not containing any spaces (hence -k 7 parameter), but it isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: why not simply doing find ... -print0 | sort -zk7rn0 ?

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot when I was looking for some large hidden files to be deleted when my Mac was running out of space :)

Answer (score 17):

With zsh and GNU ls:

```
ls -ldU -- **/*(.OL)
```

Where `(.OL)` is a [*glob qualifier*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), `.` to select *regular* files only, `OL` to reverse order by length (file size, `o`  for ascending order, `O` for descending).

(note that older versions of zsh had issues with file sizes over 2^32).

Some operating systems have a limit on the size of the argument list passed to a command. In those cases, you'd need:

```
autoload -U zargs
zargs ./**/*(.OL) -- ls -ldU
```

If you just want the list of files and not the detailed output, just do:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(N.OL)
```

If you want to include hidden files (whose name starts with a dot, except `.` and `..`) and search in hidden directories as well, add the `D` globbing qualifier:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND.OL)
```

Answer (score 11):

List files by size ascending would be:

```
ls -lSr
```

The options are:

- l: long, shows detailed user,group,other attributes, date, etc.
- S: orders listing by size (descending by default)
- r: reverses order of listing

Answer (score 9):

Saying that "the files could be present anywhere in a certain folder" implies that you want to recursively descend all directories (folders) within the starting directory (folder).  This is what `find` is meant to do:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lSd {} +
```

This "finds" all **files** in the current working directory (`.`).  For each file found, an `ls` process is run to sort the objects found in size order.  The `+` terminator to the `-exec` causes multiple arguments to be passed as a list to `ls`.  Unless your directory (folder) contains a very large number of files, you should have one list (and thus one process forked), leading to the result you desire.

Comment: this is nice as it allows you to use the -h modifier on ls to show nice file sizes

Answer (score 6):

File list display in reverse order: `ls -lSrh`

For ascending order: `ls -lSh`

Comment: +1 for using the -h flag for human-friendly output.

Answer (score 4):

Try these, it works fine for me.

`$ find /home/san -type f -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -n 10`

`# find /root -type f -exec ls -lS {} + | head -n 10 | awk '{ print $5, $9 }'`

Not perfect answer though but works to some extent

```
$ ls -lS |grep  '^-' | head -n 6
```

Comment: awk works fine if filenames don't contain any spaces.

Comment: yes .. use 'sed' and replace space with underscore? if that helps

Comment: No, I use `sed` to cut output

Answer (score 3):

Adding to delh's answer and Stéphane Chazelas' comment...

`find -print0` combined with `xargs -0` adds support for blanks / spaces / whatnots.

`du -h | sort -rn` doesn't sort properly between different byte multiples, e.g. 1.1M will show after 128K, which is wrong.

`sort -rh` (--human-numeric-sort) takes care of that, but it only works on GNU's version.

The commands below will provide the desired output.

Human-readable, on GNU's sort / Linux:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh`

In kilobyte units, on BSD / OSX / others:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -k | sort -rn`

For BSD / OSX, also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188375/82895.

Answer (score 3):

As a variation of the original question, if you want to see the cumulative size of files in the subdirectories:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
find ${1:-.} -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -sm {} \; | sort -nr
```

The sizes will be displayed in Megabytes ( the `m` in `du -sm`). Other values accepted by `du` are `-k` for kilobytes, `-g` for gigabytes. Using `-h` for human-readable display is not possible because it will break sorting.

Here is a version that uses `sed` to append the `M` for megabyte:

```bash
find ${1:-.} -maxdepth 1  -type d  -exec du -sm {} \; | sort -nr | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)/\1M/g'
```

The directory to display is set via `${1:-.}` which will use the first command line argument if provided, or use the current directory if called without arguments.

NOTE: This can take a long time with a lot of files. The option `-type d` will only list subdirectories and exclude files in the current folder; if you also want to see the files in the current folder then remove it.

> <sup>Note: you might want to use [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) instead which is available in most linux repos (on ubuntu/debian `apt install ncdu`) as well as on osx (`brew install ncdu`). Apart from visualising the sorted tree `ncdu` can also delete a selected folder with `d`.</sup>

Comment: +1 for ncdu. Nice cmd tool for browsing files sorted by size.

Comment: Another +1 for `ncdu`, nice to be reminded that the command-line doesn't always have to consist of wrestling with convoluted `find` chains to do something as basic as analysing filesizes in a directory. Also happened to already be included on my Cygwin installation, too.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something to this extent a while back. You could pass an argument to specify how many files to list, or just type `big`, in what case you get 10.

```
big () { 
    NUM_FILES=10;
    if [ $1 ]; then
        NUM_FILES=$1;
    fi;
    du | sort -nr | head -n $NUM_FILES
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### All about finding, filtering, and sorting with `find`, based on file size

### Main answer

> I would like to list all files in the order of big to small in size

I like pretty output, so here's the solution I like most. Replace the `.` right after `find` with the path to any directory you want to check:

```bash
# Sort by size (in descending order), printing size in kiB
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' | sort -rn
```

Example output when run in my `eRCaGuy_hello_world/python` dir [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/python). Notice the pretty output, sorted by kiB size, in descending order:

```
    15.280273 kiB ./hello_george.py
    11.862305 kiB ./enum_practice.py
     6.858398 kiB ./slots_practice/slots_practice.py
     6.658203 kiB ./struct_packed.py
     6.295898 kiB ./textwrap_practice_1.py
     4.714844 kiB ./raw_bytes_practice.py
     3.784180 kiB ./README.md
     3.559570 kiB ./yaml_import/import_yaml_test.py
     3.413086 kiB ./socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
     2.354492 kiB ./auto_white_balance_img.py
     2.121094 kiB ./for_loop_basic_demo.py
     1.935547 kiB ./socket_udp_send_packed_struct_TODO.py
     1.692383 kiB ./binary_tree_traverse_and_print_TODO.py
     1.633789 kiB ./system_call_subprocess_pipe.py
     1.507812 kiB ./autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py
     1.322266 kiB ./binary_tree_TODO.py
     1.116211 kiB ./change_environment_variables_in_parent_process_TODO.py
     0.938477 kiB ./hello_world.py
     0.722656 kiB ./yaml_import/my_config1.yaml
     0.708984 kiB ./yaml_import/my_config2.yaml
     0.258789 kiB ./slots_practice/Link to 10. __slots__ Magic — Python Tips 0.1 documentation%%%%%+.desktop
     0.176758 kiB ./slots_practice/Class and Instance Attributes – Real Python.desktop
     0.137695 kiB ./autogenerated/myheader.h
```

##### Explanation:

1. `-type f` finds only `f`iles
2. `-printf '%s\t%p\n'` prints the file size in bytes (`%s`), followed by a tab (`\t`), followed by the filename (`%p`). From `man find`:

   > ```
   > %p     File's name.
   > %s     File's size in bytes.
   > ```
3. The entire `awk` portion converts bytes to kiB. You can remove it to get bytes.

   **To get pretty-formatted, right-aligned bytes, or kiB, MiB, GiB, or TiB,** use the following:

   ```bash
   # bytes (ugly)
   find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -rn

   # bytes (pretty)
   find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%11i B ", $1); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn

   # kiB (kibibytes) [what I use the most]
   find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn

   # MiB (mebibytes)
   find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%13.6f MiB ", $1/(1024*1024)); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn

   # GiB (gibibytes)
   find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%13.6f GiB ", $1/(1024*1024*1024)); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn

   # TiB (tebibytes)
   find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%13.6f TiB ", $1/(1024*1024*1024*1024)); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn
   ```
4. The `sort -rn` part does a `r`everse `n`umerical sort to sort in descending order by size.

### Off on tangents: list of (closely-related or overlapping) examples I find really useful:

##### 1. (Same as previously above) Sort by size (in descending order), printing size in kiB

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn
```

Sample output is shown above.

##### 2. Sort by name

Pipe to `sort -k 3 --ignore-case` to sort by name instead.

Limitation: as it is currently written, this is only sorting by the first portion of the name up until the first space within the name, if there are spaces in the name.

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -k 3 --ignore-case
```

Example output:

```
     1.507812 kiB ./autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py
     0.137695 kiB ./autogenerated/myheader.h
     2.354492 kiB ./auto_white_balance_img.py
     1.322266 kiB ./binary_tree_TODO.py
     1.692383 kiB ./binary_tree_traverse_and_print_TODO.py
     1.116211 kiB ./change_environment_variables_in_parent_process_TODO.py
    11.862305 kiB ./enum_practice.py
     2.121094 kiB ./for_loop_basic_demo.py
    15.280273 kiB ./hello_george.py
     0.938477 kiB ./hello_world.py
     4.714844 kiB ./raw_bytes_practice.py
     3.784180 kiB ./README.md
     0.176758 kiB ./slots_practice/Class and Instance Attributes – Real Python.desktop
     0.258789 kiB ./slots_practice/Link to 10. __slots__ Magic — Python Tips 0.1 documentation%%%%%+.desktop
     6.858398 kiB ./slots_practice/slots_practice.py
     3.413086 kiB ./socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
     1.935547 kiB ./socket_udp_send_packed_struct_TODO.py
     6.658203 kiB ./struct_packed.py
     1.633789 kiB ./system_call_subprocess_pipe.py
     6.295898 kiB ./textwrap_practice_1.py
     3.559570 kiB ./yaml_import/import_yaml_test.py
     0.722656 kiB ./yaml_import/my_config1.yaml
     0.708984 kiB ./yaml_import/my_config2.yaml
```

##### 3. Only show files greater than a certain size (`-size +<number>`)

Add `-size +3k` to `find` to show only files > 3kiB, or `-size +3072c` to show only files > 3072 bytes (same thing in this case). From `man find`:

> ```
> -size n[cwbkMG]
>       File uses n units of space, rounding up.  The following suffixes can be used:
>
>       `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>
>       `c'    for bytes
>
>       `w'    for two-byte words
>
>       `k'    for Kibibytes (KiB, units of 1024 bytes)
>
>       `M'    for Mebibytes (MiB, units of 1024 * 1024 = 1048576 bytes)
>
>       `G'    for Gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073741824 bytes)
> ```

Examples

1. > 3 kiB (`-size +3k`):

   ```bash
   find . -type f -size +3k -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   15.280273 kiB ./hello_george.py
   11.862305 kiB ./enum_practice.py
    6.858398 kiB ./slots_practice/slots_practice.py
    6.658203 kiB ./struct_packed.py
    6.295898 kiB ./textwrap_practice_1.py
    4.714844 kiB ./raw_bytes_practice.py
    3.784180 kiB ./README.md
    3.559570 kiB ./yaml_import/import_yaml_test.py
    3.413086 kiB ./socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
   ```
2. > 3072 bytes (`-size +3072c`):

   ```bash
   find . -type f -size +3072c -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
       | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
       for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
       | sort -rn
   ```

   Output: exact same as just above

##### 4. Put quotes around the path

Sorted by name in this case:

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); printf("\""); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\"\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -k 3 --ignore-case
```

Output:

```
     1.507812 kiB "./autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py"
     0.137695 kiB "./autogenerated/myheader.h"
     2.354492 kiB "./auto_white_balance_img.py"
     1.322266 kiB "./binary_tree_TODO.py"
     1.692383 kiB "./binary_tree_traverse_and_print_TODO.py"
     1.116211 kiB "./change_environment_variables_in_parent_process_TODO.py"
    11.862305 kiB "./enum_practice.py"
     2.121094 kiB "./for_loop_basic_demo.py"
    15.280273 kiB "./hello_george.py"
     0.938477 kiB "./hello_world.py"
     4.714844 kiB "./raw_bytes_practice.py"
     3.784180 kiB "./README.md"
     0.176758 kiB "./slots_practice/Class and Instance Attributes – Real Python.desktop"
     0.258789 kiB "./slots_practice/Link to 10. __slots__ Magic — Python Tips 0.1 documentation%%%%%+.desktop"
     6.858398 kiB "./slots_practice/slots_practice.py"
     3.413086 kiB "./socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py"
     1.935547 kiB "./socket_udp_send_packed_struct_TODO.py"
     6.658203 kiB "./struct_packed.py"
     1.633789 kiB "./system_call_subprocess_pipe.py"
     6.295898 kiB "./textwrap_practice_1.py"
     3.559570 kiB "./yaml_import/import_yaml_test.py"
     0.722656 kiB "./yaml_import/my_config1.yaml"
     0.708984 kiB "./yaml_import/my_config2.yaml"
```

##### 5. Showing only files of a certain type (`.yaml` in this case)

Pipe to grep at the end to filter only on files of a certain type (`.yaml` in this case). Sorted by size here:

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn | grep -i '\.yaml'
```

Output:

```
     0.722656 kiB ./yaml_import/my_config1.yaml
     0.708984 kiB ./yaml_import/my_config2.yaml
```

##### 6. Showing only files NOT of a certain type (*not* `.yaml` in this case)

To *not* show files of a certain type, add `-v` to `grep` (shown as `-iv` here, since it includes `-i` still):

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn | grep -iv '\.yaml'
```

Output:

```
    15.280273 kiB ./hello_george.py
    11.862305 kiB ./enum_practice.py
     6.858398 kiB ./slots_practice/slots_practice.py
     6.658203 kiB ./struct_packed.py
     6.295898 kiB ./textwrap_practice_1.py
     4.714844 kiB ./raw_bytes_practice.py
     3.784180 kiB ./README.md
     3.559570 kiB ./yaml_import/import_yaml_test.py
     3.413086 kiB ./socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
     2.354492 kiB ./auto_white_balance_img.py
     2.121094 kiB ./for_loop_basic_demo.py
     1.935547 kiB ./socket_udp_send_packed_struct_TODO.py
     1.692383 kiB ./binary_tree_traverse_and_print_TODO.py
     1.633789 kiB ./system_call_subprocess_pipe.py
     1.507812 kiB ./autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py
     1.322266 kiB ./binary_tree_TODO.py
     1.116211 kiB ./change_environment_variables_in_parent_process_TODO.py
     0.938477 kiB ./hello_world.py
     0.258789 kiB ./slots_practice/Link to 10. __slots__ Magic — Python Tips 0.1 documentation%%%%%+.desktop
     0.176758 kiB ./slots_practice/Class and Instance Attributes – Real Python.desktop
     0.137695 kiB ./autogenerated/myheader.h
```

Or, *not* of multiple types: ignore *both* `.yaml` and `.py` files here by piping to `grep -Eiv '\.(yaml|py)'`:

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn | grep -Eiv '\.(yaml|py)'
```

Output: this leaves only .md, .desktop, and .h files for me in this case, still sorted by size:

```
     3.784180 kiB ./README.md
     0.258789 kiB ./slots_practice/Link to 10. __slots__ Magic — Python Tips 0.1 documentation%%%%%+.desktop
     0.176758 kiB ./slots_practice/Class and Instance Attributes – Real Python.desktop
     0.137695 kiB ./autogenerated/myheader.h
```

##### 7. Showing only files NOT of a certain type (*not* `.yaml` nor `.py` in this case) *and* > some size (1 kiB in this case)

Add `size +1k` back in to only show files > 1 kiB:

```bash
find . -type f -size +1k -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn | grep -Eiv '\.(yaml|py)'
```

Output: only 1 file fits this filter:

```
     3.784180 kiB ./README.md
```

##### 8. (Figure out which file extensions to add to `git lfs` next) Find all files in your git repo *not* in the `.git` folder, > 100 kiB, which are *not* PDF files nor .c nor .h files

**Note: this command is very useful when trying to figure out which binary files you should add to [`git lfs`](https://git-lfs.com/) next, in order to reduce the size of your regular git repo contents.**

Let's say you are already tracking all PDF files in `git lfs`, and you want to find all large files **> 100 kiB** now which are **not PDF, not .c, and not .h files**, so you can track those with `git lfs` next. Note that you also need to **exclude the `.git` directory**, as I explain in detail here: [How do I exclude a directory when using `find`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830768/4561887).

Here is how:

```bash
# List all files of the desired types, sorted, >100 kiB, and NOT in the .git
# dir.
# - Note that since we are using the `-i` flag with `grep`, this ignores the
#   case of the excluded files, so it
#   excludes .pdf, .PDF, .pDf, .c, .C, .h, .H, etc. 
find . -not \( -path "./.git" -type d -prune \) \
    -type f -size +100k -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn | grep -Eiv '\.(pdf|h|c)'
```

If I run this in the root of my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo I get the following output:

```
  1003.039062 kiB ./cpp/bin/c
   943.083008 kiB ./cpp/bin/a.ii
   943.055664 kiB ./cpp/bin/constexpr_max.ii
   937.910156 kiB ./cpp/bin/libgtest.a
   937.910156 kiB ./cpp/bin/1/libgtest.a
   875.296875 kiB ./cpp/bin/gtest-all.o
   827.643555 kiB ./cpp/bin_hello_world/hello_world.ii
   796.139648 kiB ./cpp/bin/class_inheritance_and_using_override_in_class.ii
   795.375000 kiB ./cpp/bin/using_override_in_class.ii
   795.291992 kiB ./cpp/bin/remove_vowels_in_string.ii
   794.961914 kiB ./cpp/bin/make_path_to_file.ii
   794.777344 kiB ./cpp/bin/hello_world_basic.ii
   777.974609 kiB ./markdown/photos/Fire_Drone_High_Quality_300x173.gif
   544.968750 kiB ./cpp/bin_hello_world/hello_world.s
   521.539062 kiB ./cpp/bin/b
   515.898438 kiB ./cpp/unordered_map_practice/unordered_map_hash_table_implicit_key_construction_test
   485.964844 kiB ./test_photos/test1.jpg
   314.006836 kiB ./markdown/photos/pranksta6.jpg
   311.539062 kiB ./cpp/bin_hello_world/hello_world.o
   283.306641 kiB ./markdown/photos/pranksta7.jpg
   278.929688 kiB ./markdown/photos/pranksta3.jpg
   216.493164 kiB ./markdown/photos/pranksta4.jpg
   214.109375 kiB ./cpp/bin/tmp
   209.582031 kiB ./cpp/bin/libgmock.a
   205.605469 kiB ./markdown/photos/pranksta5.jpg
   201.375000 kiB ./cpp/template_function_sized_array_param/template_func
   196.929688 kiB ./cpp/bin/gmock-all.o
   171.101562 kiB ./cpp/template_function_sized_array_param/regular_func
   169.750000 kiB ./cpp/bin_hello_world/hello_world
   158.937500 kiB ./cpp/bin/onlinegdb--process_10_bit_video_data
   158.906250 kiB ./cpp/bin/process_10_bit_video_data
   149.671875 kiB ./linux/systemd-by-example/README.md
   131.186523 kiB ./markdown/photos/pranksta2.jpg
```

To just see the *extensions* of these files now, let's pipe the entirety of the above to `awk '{print($3)}' | sed 's/.*\///' | grep -oE "(^[^.]*$|\.[^0-9]*\..*$)" | sort -u`. The `awk` part grabs just the path, which is the 3rd space-separated field (column) from the left. The `sed` part retains just the contents after the last `/`. The `grep` part then keeps only the extension, including the dot (`.`), if it has one, and the whole string otherwise. And finally, `sort -u` removes duplicates to leave only unique strings. (For more-advanced examples to focus on extracting more-complicated extensions, such as `.tar.gz` from `file.10.5.2.tar.gz`, see my answer here: [Grabbing the extension in a file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731665/114401)).

Here's that final command:

```bash
find . -not \( -path "./.git" -type d -prune \) \
    -type f -size +100k -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn | grep -Eiv '\.(pdf|h|c)' \
    | awk '{print($3)}' \
    | sed 's/.*\///' | grep -oE "(^[^.]*$|\.[^0-9]*\..*$)" | sort -u
```

And the output:

```
.a
b
c
.gif
hello_world
.ii
.jpg
.md
.o
onlinegdb--process_10_bit_video_data
process_10_bit_video_data
regular_func
.s
template_func
tmp
unordered_map_hash_table_implicit_key_construction_test
```

*Manually* reviewing that, I can see it might be a good idea to add the following binary extensions to be tracked by `git lfs` for this repo:

```
.gif
.jpg
.o
```

I could also optionally manually track some of those extension-less executables.

---

**Quick reference: list extensions of all files > 10 kiB in size (`-size +10k`):**
*Note: I've modified the `awk` call near the end to grab just the end of the filename (where the extension is), in case the filename has spaces in it. This is done with `awk '{print($NF)}'`:*

```bash
find . -not \( -path "./.git" -type d -prune \) \
    -type f -size +10k -printf '%s\t%p\n' \
    | awk '{printf("%13.6f kiB ", $1/(1024)); \
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("%s\n", $NF)}' \
    | sort -rn \
    | awk '{print($NF)}' \
    | sed 's/.*\///' | grep -oE "(^[^.]*$|\.[^0-9]*[\.]?[^0-9]*$)" | sort -u
```

### Going further

In the examples above, instead of using `find` with `-printf '%s\t%p\n'` to output size information, you could use `du` instead. I haven't gone down that path to get the right options and formatting I'd want, however, like I have done with `find`, so the `find` commands are good enough for now.

### References

1. ChatGPT helped me figure a lot of this out, especially getting me started on the `awk` stuff, and working on the regular expressions for `sed` and `grep`. All content above, including the code and words, however, is my own, and was written and tested directly by me.
2. I also used https://regex101.com/ to test and develop the regular expressions.
3. My answer: [How do I exclude a directory when using `find`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830768/4561887)
4. For more-advanced examples to focus on extracting more-complicated extensions, such as `.tar.gz` from `file.10.5.2.tar.gz`, see my answer here: [Grabbing the extension in a file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731665/114401)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Do I have an error or mistake (I'll fix it)? Did I not add value to the answers already here? Is it just too long for your liking?

Comment: Most of your answer assumes that names do not contain newlines (see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)). The question in furthermore not interested in recursively looking for files but are only concerned with looking in a particular directory. Your answer then continues on various tangents that are irrelevant to the question. The last two pipelines that you present could be simplified greatly by recognising that `awk`, `grep` and `sed` very seldom have to be used together (`awk` can often trivially do the job of the other two tools).

Comment: I did not downvote, but for example to exclude `.yaml` or `.py` files you can simply use: `find . ! -name '*.yaml' ! -name '*.py'` (and you avoid using the `grep`)

Comment: Answer is way long.  It does go on tangents.  And yet, the first solution is exactly what I need at 03:22 on a Monday morning to recover space on a server that will be used by several thousand people as soon as the sun comes up.  Upvoted with gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below one-liner bash shell script for listing all the files recusrively with size of files of multiple folders.
Note: Kindly change folder location according to your demand.

```
/usr/bin/du -a /var/log /home/user/log |sort -nr |awk '{print $NF}'|while read l ;do echo "file $(du -csh $l|grep -vi total) " ;done|nl
```