# how to find a file extension with multiple dots

Tags: shell-script, filenames, string

I'd like to extract the extension out of a filename with multiple dots.
For instance:

```
gbamidi-v1.0.tar.gz
```

I should get "tar.gz", not "gz" or "0.tar.gz".

I prefer a solution not relying on bash exclusive features (using posix commands like `sed` or `cut` is ok).

EDIT: A reasonable solution could be:
"get everything after the second-last dot, but exclude numbers or substrings with a lenght <=1"

Comment: Determining an extension is *hard*. Either make a list of acceptable extensions, or pick a range of acceptable number of dots.

Comment: And I suppose you have never encountered files from a simple splitting (`...0`, `...1`, etc.)?

Comment: ok, there are common single-letter file extensions like `.h`, `.a`, etc., but in this case they won't occur.

Comment: oh, sorry that i missed [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1574/31724). It fits perfectly my case.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be valid in all cases, but `.gz` is the extension. `foo.tar.gz` first has to be extracted to a `foo.tar`, then unarchived. The fact you can do that in one command is just convenience.

You need to get the extension? It's `.gz`.

If you need something else then you're going to need to target specific things using regex, `awk`, `cut` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that an extension starts with a letter after the period, the following command prints `.tar.gz`:

```
echo gbamidi-v1.0.tar.gz | awk \
    'BEGIN { FS = "\." } \
    { \
        extension = ""; \
        i = NF; \
        while ((i > 1) && (substr($i, 1, 1) ~ /[A-Za-z]/)) { \
            extension = "." $i extension; \
            i-- \
        }; \
        print extension \
    }'
```

Comment: In zsh I'd do this:

    var=\`echo version12.0.foo.tar.gz | sed 's,[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+,,'\` ; echo ${var#*.}

just strip out any decimal numbers, assign the results to variable 'var' then strip out anything up to and including the first dot from 'var'.