# linux command using trim / cut / sed to cut few data in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, cut

I have the content like below in a `/tmp/myfileslist`

```
test1/a/sample1.xls
test2/demo.sh
```

I want to remove .extentions and content before slash , also slash is to be removed.I want the output as

```
sample1
demo
```

Comment: WHat did you try so far?

Comment: i tried this command
cat  /tmp/myfileslist | cut -d/ -f 2
Output:
a
demo.sh

Comment: add this to the question, not in comment

Comment: What about `test3/foo.tar.gz`? Do you want `foo` or `foo.tar`?

Comment: Is Perl an option? Or Perl6 (a.k.a. Raku)?

Comment: Also, is there always an extension, or can there be files without extension (as in `test4/d/noext`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` (and it's assumed that there in no repeated *dot* suffixes in your records such as `/path/to/some.example.txt` as it will then return "*example*" part only)

```
awk -F'[/.]' '{ print $(NF-1) }' infile
```

if you have such records like that,  use below instead.

```
awk -F'/' '{ sub(/.[^.]*$/, ""); print $NF }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

You `cut` approach has the problem that the number of the field changes from line to line.

Also note that "you shall not pipe `cat`s", instead give the filename as attribute to your text processing command.

Do it in two steps to remove everything upto the slash (`.*/`) and then everything starting from the dot (`\..*`):

```
 sed 's_.*/__;s_\..*__' /tmp/myfilelist
```

*(This assumes you want to remove all extensions and you only want the `foo` of `foo.tar.gz`.)*

Comment: I should add, that if you only want to remove the last extension, the second `s`ubstitute command turns into `s_\.[^.]*$__`

Comment: Thank you so much this command is working 
awk -F'[/.]' '{ print $(NF-1) }' /tmp/mytestfiles

Answer (score 1):

#### cut

You can grab the last element with `cut` if you reverse each line first, e.g.:

```
<filelist.txt rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
```

Now you can remove the filename extension like this:

```
<filelist.txt rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | cut -d. -f1
```

#### bash

Besides `cut` and `sed` you could use [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove the path filename extension, e.g.:

```bash
while read f; do
  f="${f##*/}"
  f="${f%.*}"
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
done < filelist.txt
```

Hint: use `${f%%.*}` to remove all extensions.

Comment: As one might have files with dots in the name (e.g. `file.123.suf`), I'd suggest doing the suffix removal `cut`ting in the reversed form: `<filelist.txt rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d'.' -f1 --complement | rev`

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put .IO.extension("").basename;'  file

#OR (below handles up to 8-part extensions):

~$ raku -ne 'put .IO.extension("", :parts(^9)).basename;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
/test1/a/sample1.xls
/test2/demo.sh
/some/file.txt
/whatever/prog.c
/something/abc.tar.bz
/something/abc.123.456.789.tar.bz
/something/abc.c
/something/abc.h
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever
/path/to/file.10.5.2.tar.gz.whatever.7.pdf
/noextension
```

Sample Output:

```
sample1
demo
file
prog
abc
abc
abc
abc
file
file
file
noextension
```

Briefly, the file is read linewise using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. The code is run over each line: First the path is interpreted as an `IO` object, for which an `extension` can be identified/modified. Within the `extension` parameters, the identified parts are `""` substituted with nothing (i.e. deleted). Adding the `:parts` parameter (a.k.a. "adverb") allows multi-part file-extension identification. Finally, the `basename` is isolated, removing all parts of the path--slash and above.

Note, because filepaths are understood by Raku with OS-specific settings, the codes above *should work* unmodified on Windows to extract the correct elements from Windows paths (Raku understands backslash as a path-separator on Windows OS).

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Path
https://docs.raku.org/routine/basename
https://docs.raku.org/routine/extension
https://raku.org

Example Source:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731665/227738